# Draw dash border with mouse over on Fabric JS

Tags: canvas, fabricjs

I need to add this kind of dash border when mouse over the fabric js component. And I want to clear it with mouse out event

[image]

How can I handle it? any suggestion?

I tried with strike, it worked but I need dash border, any suggestion?

```
canvas.on('mouse:over', function (opt) {
  const t1 = opt.target;
  if (t1) {
    t1.set({
      stroke: 'red',
      strokeWidth: 3,
      dirty: true
    });
    canvas.requestRenderAll();
  }
});

canvas.on('mouse:out', function (opt) {
  const t1 = opt.target;
  if (t1) {
    t1.set({
      stroke: 'black',
      strokeWidth: 0,
      dirty: true
    });
    canvas.requestRenderAll();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    canvas.on('mouse:over', function (opt) {
      const { target } = opt;
    
      if (!target) return;
    
        target._renderControls(canvas.contextTop, {
          hasControls: false,
        });
    });

    canvas.on('mouse:out', function (opt) {
       canvas.clearContext(canvas.contextTop);
    });
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).